# How do i Add a license to a user or see if they already have it?

Tags: c#

I have the License ID with this code, but i dont know where to go from here. Brain fart for the last hour and google isnt my friend today.

**How do I first check to see if the user has this License?**

**How do i then Give them the license if they don't have it?**

```
    private void AssignPackageLicenses()
    {                       
        QueryResult queryPackageLicenses = null;
        String SOQL = "";
        SOQL = "SELECT Id, NamespacePrefix, AllowedLicenses, UsedLicenses, ExpirationDate, Status FROM PackageLicense WHERE NamespacePrefix = 'SVMXC'";
        queryPackageLicenses = Sfdcbinding.query(SOQL);            

        string SVMXCID = null;
        string namespacePrefix = null;
        int? allowedLicenses = null;
        int? usedLicenses = null;
        string expirationDate = null;
        string status = null;            
        int? licensesLeft = null;

        try
        {
            if (queryPackageLicenses.size > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < queryPackageLicenses.size; i++)
                {
                    PackageLicense pl = (PackageLicense)queryPackageLicenses.records[i];
                    SVMXCID = pl.Id;
                    namespacePrefix = pl.NamespacePrefix;
                    allowedLicenses = pl.AllowedLicenses;
                    usedLicenses = pl.UsedLicenses;
                    expirationDate = pl.ExpirationDate.ToString();
                    status = pl.Status;
                    string[] packLicense = { SVMXCID, namespacePrefix, expirationDate, status };
                    int?[] packLicense1 = { allowedLicenses, usedLicenses };
                    licensesLeft = (allowedLicenses - usedLicenses);
                    lblSvmxcID.Text = SVMXCID;
                    lblLicensesLeft.Text = licensesLeft.ToString();
                }
                ///How do i check if user has License already?
                ///How do i give the license to the user?
            }
        }
        catch (SoapException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An unexpected error has occurred: " +
                         e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the way i checked to see if they had the license already..

```
            string uplID = null;
            string SVMXCuserId = null;
            QueryResult queryUsersWithSVMXC = null;
            String SOQL_Users = "";
            SOQL_Users = "SELECT Id, UserId from UserPackageLicense where PackageLicenseID = " + "'" + SVMXCID + "'";  // ID 05040000000TQfcAAG
            queryUsersWithSVMXC = Sfdcbinding.query(SOQL_Users);
            for (int i = 0; i < queryUsersWithSVMXC.size; i++)
            {
                UserPackageLicense upl = (UserPackageLicense)queryUsersWithSVMXC.records[i];
                uplID = upl.Id;
                SVMXCuserId = upl.UserId;
                string[] uplInfo = { uplID, SVMXCuserId };
                listSVMXC.AddRange(uplInfo);
                if (lblUserID.Text == SVMXCuserId)
                {
                    rdbYes.Checked = true;
                    lblSVMXCUserId.Text = SVMXCuserId;
                    break;
                }                      
            }
```

This will add a specific license to a user. this was the way i did it. Only posting for others to benefit from.

```
    private void AssignPackageLicense()
    {
        bool licenseNeeded = true;

            //Does this user need this license?            
            if (rdbYes.Checked == true)
            {
                ///Validate the user needs the license Need more code here*********
                licenseNeeded = true;
                if (licenseNeeded == true)
                {
                    string svmxcId = lblSvmxcID.Text;
                    UserPackageLicense createUPL = new UserPackageLicense();
                    createUPL.PackageLicenseId = svmxcId;
                    createUPL.UserId = lblUserID.Text;

                    try
                    {
                        SaveResult[] saveResults = Sfdcbinding.create(new sObject[] { createUPL });
                        QueryAssignPackageLicenses();
                    }
                    catch (SoapException e)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("An unexpected error has occurred: " +
                                     e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                rdbNo.Checked = true;
                MessageBox.Show("This user does not need this license");
                return;
            }          
    }
```